# simple-oauth2 throws "The content-type is not JSON compatible" on token refresh

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, simple-oauth2

I'm using simple-oauth2 in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node) to query Microsoft Graph. All works well so far. But when I try to refresh the access token `var newToken = await storedToken.refresh();`, I get an error:

> The content-type is not JSON compatible

This is thrown in `wreck`'s `index.js` and it seems like there is no `content-type` set in the headers, while the `mode` is set to `strict`. The problem is, that I have no idea how to change this or why this is happening. It only happens on `refresh()`.

Comment: So, your refresh token code looks exactly like this? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/blob/master/tutorial/04-add-aad-auth.md#user-content-refreshing-tokens

Comment: Yes, exactly. The only thing I added was a `true || ` in `if (storedToken.expired()) ` to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this is a configuration problem. The sample provides the config as follows

```
OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
OAUTH_ID_METADATA=/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

wreck uses [Url.URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_url_input_base) to combine `OAUTH_AUTHORITY` with `OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT` which results in `https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/v2.0/token` and therefore loses `common`. This results in a `404` and therefore no JSON response anymore.

I changed the config slightly and removed the leading slashes from the relative paths and added a trailing slash to the base URL.

```
OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/
OAUTH_ID_METADATA=/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=oauth2/v2.0/token
```

So that `OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT` is relative. I have not figured why it worked for authorize though, but still works.